# RVM installed but not working?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm

I installed RVM on my Fedora 19 system a few months ago, and it was working fine. Then I had some other work and when I opened the machine again, it said:

```
# rvm
bash: rvm: command not found...
```

I tried to reinstall RVM, and this is what I get:

```
# rpm -i rvm-devel-1.17-8.fc19.x86_64.rpm 
    package rvm-devel-1.17-8.fc19.x86_64 is already installed
```

But I can't find it.

```
# ps ax | grep rvm
14363 pts/0    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto rvm
```

Can anyone help me? What exactly is the problem?

P.S: The package rvm is there on the system.

```
# rpm -q rvm
rvm-1.17-8.fc19.x86_64
```

Comment: Which output produce the bash commend `rpm -ql rvm-devel|grep scripts`? And is there the `rvm` (not `rvm-devel`) package exists?

Comment: The command outputs nothing. And yeah, the package (rvm) exists.
# rpm -q rvm
rvm-1.17-8.fc19.x86_64

Comment: ok, `rpm -ql rvm|grep scripts`

Comment: Surprisingly, this too isn't giving any output!

Comment: Did you do a system wide installation or a single user install?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know the difference! I mean I just downloaded the package (the machine doesn't have internet connection) and installed it.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to reinstall RVM, maybe it's crashed due to some event.

Use this command to implode it:

```
rvm implode
```

Or:

```
rm -rf ~/.rvm
```

Then install it by running:

```
sudo apt-get install curl
curl -L get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --auto
```

Then you'll need to reload the ~/.bash_profile file which you can do with this small command:

```
. ~/.bash_profile
```

Make sure to install other packages needed for Ruby to work:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential openssl libreadline6 libreadline6-dev curl git-core zlib1g zlib1g-dev libssl-dev libyaml-dev libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 libxml2-dev libxslt-dev autoconf libc6-dev ncurses-dev automake libtool bison subversion pkg-config

sudo apt-get install pkgconfig
```

Now install the latest Ruby:

```
rvm install 2.0.0
rvm use 2.0.0
ruby -v
```

Now you can install Rails:

```
gem install rails -v 4.0.0
```

Comment: Looks RVM not working at all, try second command: "rm -rf ~/.rvm"

Answer (score 1):

the package `rvm-devel-1.17-8.fc19.x86_64` is not `rvm` as per http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/20537074/dir/fedora_19/com/rvm-devel-1.17-8.fc19.x86_64.rpm.html it is:

> The rvm-devel package contains libraries and header files for
>   developing applications that use rvm.

Follow installation instructions http://rvm.io/rvm/install to get RVM installed, make sure to read the outputs as important hints might be printed for you.

Answer (score 0):

to uninstall rvm use anyone of the following:

```
rvm implode
```

or

```
rm -rf ~/.rvm
```

Just to be sure restart the terminal before you try installing rvm again